# Why exception caught without throwing in C++?

Tags: c++, exception

I am running this program. As per my understanding, there should be a bad allocation exception raised within the try block and should cause a runtime failure. However, the program executes without any problem. I have the following questions:

1. Why is there no run-time error?
2. How does the control reach catch block even when no exceptions were thrown?

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   int main() {
       int b =4, *c = NULL, i=-1;
       try{
           c = new int [i]; 
           b--;
       }catch (exception& e){
           cout << "coming here" << endl;
           c = new int[1];
           b++;
       }
       cout << b << endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: For me, it comes in the catch block. Where did you run this?

Comment: How this is supposed to behave depends on the language version. Until C++11, it has undefined behaviour and shouldn't do anything in particular.

Comment: The exception **is** the run-time error you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-1` will be converted to the `std::size_t` value `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()` due to the implicit conversion to an unsigned type. It is indeed unlikely that you have that much memory available.

However a `std::bad_alloc` *might* not be thrown if your operating system doesn't actually allocate the memory until you consume it (common on linux platforms).

See [lazy allocation for c++ object arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931311/lazy-allocation-for-c-object-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Your `c = new int [i]` within the try block throws the exception because it cannot allocate the memory (i=-1), so the catch block will be executed.